# Android can not represent unicode for treble clef (Unicode 8 or 16?)

Tags: java, android, unicode, symbols

I want to represent the treble clef symbol in my app. Ive tried it with

```
textField.setText("\uD834\uDD1E");
```

(is this UTF-8 combined representation?)
But it just gave me an rectangle symbol. Android doesnt know it.

How do i enter the UTF-16 code U+1D11E in java?

i also tried it in xml:

```
&#x1d11e;
```

Same result. So how can i enter this symbol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a font that has that character.

Comment: Thank you. Could you help me out how to do so? Do i need to download a font?

Comment: Download a new font, and then use `android:typeface` in your TextView's xml.

Comment: Thanks that helped